# why pandas df.drop() doesn't drop all indexes unless inplace used

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I started writing this question in other form, but found a solution in the meantime. I have a dataframe shaped like 55k x 4. Since couple of hours now I couldn't understand why I can't drop rows I need to drop. I had something like that:

```py
print(df.shape)
indexes_to_drop = list()

for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    if some_complex_function(row[1]):
        indexes_to_drop.append(row[0])

print(len(indexes_to_drop))
df = df.drop(index=indexes_to_drop)
print(df.shape)
```

My output was like:

```
55000 x 4
2500
52500 x 4
```

However, once I displayed some rows from my df I was still able to find rows I thought were deleted. Ofc 1st thought was to check `some_complex_function`. But I logged everything it did, and it was just fine.

So, I tried couple other ways of deleting rows using index, for example:

`df = df.drop(df.index[ignore_indexes])`
Still, shape is ok, but not the rows.

Then I tried with `iterrows()` instead of `itertuples`. Same thing.

I thought maybe there is something wrong with indexing. You know: index number vs index label. I tested my code on small dataframe and everything worked like a charm.

Then I realized, I do some stuff with my df before I run above, code. So I reset the index before like that:
`df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` Indexes changed, started counting from 0, but my results were still wrong.

Then I tried this: `df.drop(index=indexes_to_drop, inplace=True)`
And BOOM it worked.

Right now Im not looking for the solution, as I apparently found one. I'd like to know WHY dropping rows not "inplace" didn't work. I don't get that.

Cheers!

Comment: `df.drop(index=indexes_to_drop)` returns an object.  Since you didn't do `df = df.drop(index=indexes_to_drop)`, the returned data was lost.  From the documentation _inplace : bool, default False
    If True, do operation inplace and return None._

Comment: I did, you can see that in the 1st snippet. just hasn't pointed it out later on. Will edit the question, so it would be more precise. Thanks for the comment, tho!

Comment: Nevertheless, in case you described, df after the drop should have the old shape. Nothing was supposed to change in that situation, because new object was created. And like I said, I had dropped rows, just wrong ones for some reason.